# SQL Query Unclear

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I am trying to create a query that returns a specific set of registers, but i tried several ways and it is not working.

I have 4 tables like below:

```
recipe {
    idRecipe integer,
    name varchar(100)
}

recipeStep {
    idStep integer,
    idRecipe integer,
    instruction varchar(100)
}

recipeIngredient {
    idStep integer,
    idIngredient integer
}

ingredient {
    idIngredient integer,
    name varchar(100)
}
```

- A recipe can have ONE or MORE steps;
- A step can be part of only ONE recipe;
- A step can have ONE or MORE ingredient;
- An ingredient can be part of ONE or MORE steps;

The filter is to return all recipe that contain the ingredients selected by the user. Lets say i want all recipes that contains all recipes connotation the ingredients 68,25,36,109. So I came to this:

```
SELECT r.* 
  FROM recipe r, recipeStep rs, recipeIngredient ri 
 WHERE r.idRecipe = rs.idRecipe
   AND rs.idStep = ri.idStep
   AND ri.idIngredient in (68,25,36,109)
```

The problem is that this query returns ALL recipes that contains ANY of those ingredients and I want only ALL recipes that contains ALL of them

Comment: The query you show probably returns each recipe as many times as it has matching ingredients - so you can group by the recipe(id) and count the distinct ingredients to see if there is enough of them (4 in your case).

Comment: @ jkavalik. I was about to give the same advise =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `group by` clause together with a `having` clause that limits the groups to the ones that have a count of 4 distinct ingredients.

```
SELECT r.idRecipe, r.name
  FROM recipe r
  JOIN recipeStep rs ON r.idRecipe = rs.idRecipe
  JOIN recipeIngredient ri ON rs.idStep = ri.idStep
 WHERE ri.idIngredient IN (68,25,36,109)
GROUP BY r.idRecipe, r.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ri.idIngredient) = 4;
```

Alternatively you could skip the IN predicate and use conditional aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT r.idRecipe, r.name
  FROM recipe r
  JOIN recipeStep rs ON r.idRecipe = rs.idRecipe
  JOIN recipeIngredient ri ON rs.idStep = ri.idStep
GROUP BY r.idRecipe, r.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ri.idIngredient = 68  THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN ri.idIngredient = 25  THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN ri.idIngredient = 36  THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN ri.idIngredient = 109 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Both queries would allow additional ingredients, as long as the recipe has the four mandatory ones. If you want exact matches you can just add another condition to the where clause.

Comment: I would guess that the second query is not efficient as it cannot use index on `ri.idIngredient` so it will do a full table scan.

Comment: @jkavalik That is probably true, if the where clause is put back into the second query it should be able to use an index. I just wanted to show another way.

Comment: And it is quite an interesting one, but if you could please add the WHERE, and maybe remove the `r.name` from GROUP BY as it is redundat and slows things down too. (It is needed before 5.6 with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` activated, but not either without it nor in 5.7 which can detect functional dependencies)